# How to merge DataFrames, combining columns and creating new rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, cartesian-product

I have a couple of arcs dataframes with a very similar structure to these:

| Ah: |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | i | j |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |

| K: |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | Ok | Dk |
| 0 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |

I need to find a way to create a new dataframe that merges both, following this structure:

| Route: |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Ok | i | j | Dk |
| 0 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 7 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 8 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 9 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 10 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 11 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 |

or this structure:

| Route: |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | i | j | k |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 9 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 10 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 11 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

Currently I have a piece of code that can do something similar to that but instead of a pandas dataframe (which is what I want to use) I'm using dictionaries (the reason behind that is that each "route" has different caracteristics that makes them unique from each other so a dictionary is useful and at the time I was just learning Python) but the issue is that it takes too much time and uses a lot of memory so I'm trying to find a way to make it a little bit quicker, avoiding 'for' loops and trying to apply Pandas to create the merged dataframe.

This is an extract of the structure of my current piece of code, for this example, consider the 'A' dataframe as the one that holds every combination possible of arcs so the 'if' condition makes sure that a connection exists before creating the route.

```
routes = {}
for k in K:
    for (i,j) in Ah:
        if (Ok,i) in A and (j,Dk) in A:
            routes[i,j,k] = [Here goes a lot of caracteristics of the route]
```

Comment: Can you clarify the "Needs to be removed!" are you saying the row should not be in the resulting frame, or are you literally looking for an indicator column that contains the words "Needs to be removed!"? TLDR; Can you clarify what your expected output is _exactly_ how it should appear?

Comment: I removed the "Needs to be removed" commentaries to avoid confusion, my output should be any of the two "route" structures above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cross [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge) for the first:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df2, df1, how='cross')[['Ok', 'i', 'j', 'Dk']]
```

`df3`:

```
    Ok  i  j  Dk
0    3  1  1   4
1    3  1  2   4
2    3  2  1   4
3    3  2  2   4
4    1  1  1   2
5    1  1  2   2
6    1  2  1   2
7    1  2  2   2
8    2  1  1   1
9    2  1  2   1
10   2  2  1   1
11   2  2  2   1
```

Cross merge with the index for the second:

```
df4 = pd.merge(df2.index.to_frame(name='k'), df1, how='cross')[['i', 'j', 'k']]
```

`df4`:

```
    i  j  k
0   1  1  0
1   1  2  0
2   2  1  0
3   2  2  0
4   1  1  1
5   1  2  1
6   2  1  1
7   2  2  1
8   1  1  2
9   1  2  2
10  2  1  2
11  2  2  2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use pandas Concat function to merge your dictionaries the way you want to. `https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html`

It's kind of hard to see how you want it to be laid out, but I think you want to use `.merge`

Comment: Thanks! this was actually close to what i needed